# Multi language web application using angularjs with laravel-5

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

There is one dropdown. Dropdown contains multiple languages. When I select language from dropdown,**language should change for whole application**.
How can I implement this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Typical answer: What have you tried so far? 
This can be done in many variantions. One might be that you save all your output in tables and add a language prefix to tables or rows with different languages. If you select another language the query for EN gets executed and you get all english content...

Comment: Saving output (all labels, static content) into table is not good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/)

With this you can load translations from string/localfile/server API/whatever and you can switch language in real time.

Hope that help